# Python scapy show ip of the ping (echo) requests

Tags: python, tcp, scapy, sniffer

I want to grab and print the source address of the ping requests.
I have the following script:

```
pkt = sniff(filter="icmp", timeout =15, count = 15)
if pkt[ICMP].type == '8':
    print pkt[IP].src
```

When a packet arrives script crashes with

```
 AttributeError:'list' object has no attribute 'type'
```

However on the scapy console I can see clearly that this exist!

```
>>>packet=IP()/ICMP()/"AAAAAA"
>>>packet[ICMP].type
8
>>>
```

Any thoughts??

I changed for testing purposes (!) my script to the following:

```
pkts=sniff(filter="icmp", timeout=120,count=15)

for packet in pkts:
    if packet.haslayer(IP) and str(packet.getlayer(IP).src)=="127.0.0.1"
       print "packet arrived"
           if packet.haslayer(ICMP) and str(packet.getlayer(ICMP).type)=="8":
                print(packet[IP].src)
```

The above after doing a ping:

```
ping localhost -c 3
```

produces the following awkward result:

```
packet arrived
127.0.0.1
packet arrived
127.0.0.1
packet arrived
packet arrived
packet arrived
127.0.0.1
packet arrived
127.0.0.1
packet arrived
packet arrived
packet arrived
127.0.0.1
packet arrived
127.0.0.1
packet arrived
```

We can ignore the "packet arrived" multiple times because other packets are reaching my host as well. But why I see 6 times the 127.0.0.1 when I sent 3 echo requests ? Even if I remove the for loop the same results are happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple packets so you can either index or iterate over:

```
from scapy.all import *
pkts = sniff(filter="icmp", timeout =15,count=15)

for packet in pkts:
     if  str(packet.getlayer(ICMP).type) == "8": 
        print(packet[IP].src)
```

Or using indexing to get the forst packet:

```
from scapy.all import *
pkts = sniff(filter="icmp", timeout =15,count=15)

if pkts  and str(pkts[0].getlayer(ICMP).type) == "8": 
        print(pkts[0][IP].src)
```

Comment: Here im not using the [0] though.. and the same thing is happening http://www.picpaste.com/pics/icmp_problem-g3q981FT.1429788898.png

Comment: add a `print(pkts.summary())` before the loop, then tell me what does not match up

Comment: LOL. thats quite interesting... There is a problem here obviously...


Is this a bug in scapy?? http://www.picpaste.com/pics/scapy_hmmm_-IKNMgx5i.1429789818.png  
http://www.picpaste.com/pics/ICMP_LOL-VC2psSk5.1429789532.png


It looks like it duplicates the entries somehow... You can see from my tcpdump (which definitely doesnt lie) that I send 3 requests and 3 responses came back... Where scapy shows them 2 times... What do you think??

Comment: If you `ping -c 3 localhost` and set count to 3 what do you get?

Comment: This is the first screenshot from my previous message.. the -c 3 sends 3 echo requests as we know... But scapy for a reason sees this process 2 times ( 6 requests - 6 responses)...

Comment: Yes but what happens when you lower the count to 3?

Comment: you can also remove  the  haslayer when filtering

Comment: Thats something interesting... So the count is for all the packets and not for the packets in filter I guess. When I set it to 3 and I ping usually it grabs the 2 requests + 1 more random packet... I tried the count=7 and the random results started happening... ping 3 times see 4 times the IP.src.. I think count doesnt work as intended..

Comment: I removed count completely... Still duplicated results.. I also removed the haslayer.. I think there is something else here related to sniff() itself maybe.

Answer (score 1):

What `sniff()` returns is not a list of packets, even though you can iterate over it as if it was a list. See below example:

```
>>> from scapy.all import *
>>> pkts = sniff(count = 15)
>>> pkts
<Sniffed: TCP:4 UDP:4 ICMP:0 Other:7>
>>> pkts[TCP]
<TCP from Sniffed: TCP:4 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>
>>>
```

If `sniff()` simply returned a list of packets, `pkt[ICMP]` in your example would never work. What `pkt[ICMP]` does is that it retrieves a list of all ICMP packets in `pkt`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That was helpful actually.. But why the 
     for packet in pkts: 
            if packet.haslayer(ICMP) and str(packet.getlayer(ICMP).type)=="8":
       print (packet[IP].src)
produces duplicate results?? Thanks

Comment: Because when you `ping localhost` both your source and destination IP addresses are `127.0.0.1`. So both the echo request and echo reply has the source IP address of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: but I have also an if statement for picking only the echo requests